# How can I configure WordPress to communicate over HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, http, elementor

I am facing a situation where I need to communicate with an HTTP URL from my WordPress site. I'm trying to insert HTML code into specific pages or posts to establish communication with a particular HTTP URL. However, WordPress automatically changes the URL to HTTPS, attempting to establish communication over a secure connection.

The problem is that the target URL does not support HTTPS, causing issues with communication. Therefore, I want to configure WordPress to communicate with this URL over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Since I have access to the server code through WordPress, I'm considering making changes on the server-side to force the URL to use HTTP. I'm looking for advice on how to modify the server code to achieve this.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions related to this issue. Thank you!

Comment: see wordpress.stackexchange.com: [Stop WordPress from using HTTPS and just use HTTP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221850/stop-wordpress-from-using-https-and-just-use-http)

Comment: Confused here. You want to « insert HTML code to establish communication with a particular HTTP URL »? Html is not used for communicating. Do you mean javascript?

Comment: It may be strange to respond using a translator. I apologize in advance. I tried http communication using JAVA Script using HTML widget. I still have the same problem, but I tried https to calm it down for now. If you have a solution, I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know.